# Define gradient of AppBar in AppBarTheme within ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I am trying to create the application theme data in a `flutter` and while defining the `ThemeData` i want to customize the `AppBar` of my application with the gradient look. Now, in `ThemeData` we have `AppBarTheme` option but not sure how to define gradient using `AppBarTheme`.

However, using `AppBar` in `Scaffold` i am able to define the gradient but looking for a way to define it in `ThemeData`

Following is the working code of gradient but in Scaffold, not sure how would I add the `flexibleSpace` in `AppBarTheme`

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       
        title: Text(
          'Dashboard',
        ),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: <Color>[
                const Color(0xFFD26934),
                const Color(0xFFFF9B44),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Would like to define gradient here

```
ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Lato-Regular',
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package:flutter/material` attempts to implement Google's Material Design: https://material.io/design

This is a specific set of style guidelines, developed by Google, and puts certain rules in place. One of the rules that they put in place is that app bars should be a solid colour (i.e. not a gradient).

Because Flutter tries to match this spec, it doesn't allow gradients in `AppBar` widgets. But you can always make your own.

For example:

```dart
class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DecoratedBox(
    child: Text('My Title'),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: // your gradient here
    ),
  );

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(double.infinity, 60);  
}
```

Note, if you want to pass your custom app bar to `Scaffold.appBar` it needs to implement `PreferredSizeWidget` and override `preferredSize` so the scaffold knows how big to make it.

You will also probably want to extract things like `title`, `actions`, etc into parameters to `GradientAppBar` so you can reuse it

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible. You sadly enough cannot assign a gradient to a color. The only way is with the flexibleSpace.

```
appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(widget.title),
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: <Color>[
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.blue
                ])          
             ),        
         ),      
     ),
```